# How to install react-native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to install react native through npm, and I've got a mistake in the console

Air-Anton: ant anton$ `npm i -g create-react-native-app`

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
> npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall access npm
> ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission
> denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!   stack: 'Error:
> EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'',
> npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall:
> 'access', npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' } npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/anton/.npm/_logs/2018-08-12T16_40_46_899Z-debug.log Air-Anton:
> ant anton$

Help how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you run the terminal as Administrator? (assumed you're using windows)

Comment: Follow this guide from NPM to fix your users permissions (u should'nt use sudo with npm i):  https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need root privileges to install react native cli since you don't have the right perms to install binaries in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

Run the same command with sudo or login temporarily as root. Try the following

```
$ sudo npm i -g create-react-native-app
```

Alternatively, you could login as root

```
$ su
[Enter root password]
# npm i -g create-react-native-app
```

Comment: I type su, after I cant type any password -(

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: mac, its first day of my experience with it, so Im a little bit shocked how its different with windows

Comment: Glad you were able to. Please mark the solution if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u have completed all the Prerequisites:

- Xcode (iOS)
- Android Studio (Android)
- Visual Studio Code (IDE)

Update command line tools in Xcode.

Install Dependencies

- Install Homebrew: https://brew.sh/

> 1. brew install node
> 2. brew install watchman

CocoaPods: https://cocoapods.org/

- sudo gem install cocoapods

Now, we are good to create our first React Native application:

- Step 1: Create a react-native application

> npx react-native@latest init FirstProject

- Step 2: Start Metro

> npm start

- Step 3: Start your application

> npm run ios